# How to convert a Python String to a dict without eval

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a string like this

```
"{""netPrice"":251.6,""totalPrice"":299.4,""calculatedTaxes"":[{""tax"":47.8,""taxRate"":19.0,""price"":251.6,""extensions"":[]}],""taxRules"":[{""taxRate"":19.0,""percentage"":100.0,""extensions"":[]}],""positionPrice"":232.0,""rawTotal"":299.4,""taxStatus"":""net""}"
```

and i need it to be an dict like `{'netPrice': 251.6, 'totalPrice':299.4, and so on}`
but since it hast the double quotes eval and json doesnt work for this.
I import that string out of a csv file with

```
with open('order.csv', 'r') as csv_datei:
    for row in csv_datei:
```

so i cant get it in a cleaner format as far as i know. (the String is the row)

How do I convert it into a dict?

Comment: That is not a valid string literal. How did you get it? Can you `print(repr(str))` to check exactly what is in it? It looks like it might be a JSON string. If so, use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) on it.

Comment: If that is an exact representation of a row in your `order.csv` file, as it seems like the result of encoding JSON into CSV, use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read it, then `json.loads` to parse it.

Comment: i tried json.loads but this also doesnt convert it into a dict. here comes the error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)

Comment: i got the string out of an csv file which i got out of an database.

Comment: and if i run ```print(repr(str))``` i get ```'"{""netPrice"":251.6,""totalPrice"":299.4,""calculatedTaxes"":[{""tax"":47.8,""taxRate"":19.0,""price"":251.6,""extensions"":[]}],""taxRules"":[{""taxRate"":19.0,""percentage"":100.0,""extensions"":[]}],""positionPrice"":232.0,""rawTotal"":299.4,""taxStatus"":""net""}"\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, this seems to be a JSON that has been placed inside CSV. Standard CSV surrounds string values with double quotes (`"..."`), and uses double double-quotes (`""`) to denote a double-quote character (`"`) inside a string.

As it is doubly encoded, pass it through both of the relevant parsers:

```
import csv
import json

with open('order.csv', 'r') as csv_datei:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_datei):
        data = json.loads(row[0])
        print(data)

# => {'netPrice': 251.6, 'totalPrice': 299.4, 'calculatedTaxes': [{'tax': 47.8, 'taxRate': 19.0, 'price': 251.6, 'extensions': []}], 'taxRules': [{'taxRate': 19.0, 'percentage': 100.0, 'extensions': []}], 'positionPrice': 232.0, 'rawTotal': 299.4, 'taxStatus': 'net'}
```

Comment: when i run it with json.loads I get the following error: ```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```

Comment: `print(row)` before `data = ...` to see exactly what data you are having a problem with. I checked that it works with the row you posted.

Comment: it works thanks i didnt add the csv.reader befor my csv_datei